# How do I use Assertation (JUnit) to check an int?

Tags: java, junit

I'm working on testing a method that is of the data type int. It accepts 2 ints as its parameters, and return which is the larger number. How do I properly call this from my test package?  Here is my code so far:

```
public void testFindMaxNum()
{
    assertEquals("findMaxNum(FAILS)", ProgrammingProject4.findMaxNum(1,2),1);
    assertEquals("findMaxNum(PASS)", ProgrammingProject4.findMaxNum(1,2),;
}
```

Comment: Well, to start, we need to know _what_ that code is doing right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the code that this is calling (findMaxNum) it is hard to be completely accurate in my answer. However, it looks like you are missing some annotations from your Test class.

I am going to assume that the signature of your method findMaxNum looks like the following:

```
public int findMaxNum(int i, int j)
```

Based on this your test code should look something like the following:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ProgrammingProject4Test {

  @Test
  public void testFindMaxNumFirst() {
    // Arrange
    ProgrammingProject4 programmingProject4 = new ProgrammingProject4();

    // Act and Assert
    assertEquals("First number should be bigger than second",2, programmingProject4.findMaxNum(1,2));
  }

  @Test
  public void testFindMaxNumSecond() {
    // Arrange
    ProgrammingProject4 programmingProject4 = new ProgrammingProject4();

    // Act and Assert
    assertEquals("Second number should be bigger,2, programmingProject4.findMaxNum(2,1));
  }
}
```

Couple of things to note from your code:

1. You are missing the annotations for the testing framework e.g. @Test. This means your build tool won't be able to find and run the tests.
2. You have the expected result after the result from the method. In JUnit asserts they should be the other way (as per my example).
3. Your code runs two tests in one method. This is bad practice because it makes debugging the tests harder. Also if the first assert fails the second one won't be run. Therefore splitting the two tests into two different methods is better.

You can take a look at Diffblue's playground (full disclosure I work for Diffblue), this is a tool that will write unit tests for a small sample piece of Java code. https://playground.diffblue.com

Hope this all makes sense. There are quite a few points in the answer. Feel free to comment if anything needs clarifying.